# Can you truncate results of a databound templatefield in a gridview?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I've got a field that retrieves a folder path. However it makes the column width too wide. I was wondering if there was a way to truncate the returned value so I can show just the file name without it's path.

```
 <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-CssClass="columnWidth"
  HeaderText="File Name " SortExpression="FileName">
     <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" 
         Text='<%# Bind("FileName")%>'></asp:Label>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="download" 
         CausesValidation="false" OnClick="download_Click" 
         CommandArgument="<% %>" CommandName="Download"  
         Text='<%#Bind("FileName")%>'></asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridHeader columnWidth" ForeColor="#A1ADBB" />
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.aspx file

```
<asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" 
Text='<%# GetFileName( Convert.ToString( Eval("FilePath") ) ) %>'
</asp:Label>
```

.cs file

```
using System.IO;

protected string GetImagePath( string FilePath)
{
    return Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
}
```